# R script error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Calls: aggregate

Tags: r, powerbi, rscript, forecast

I am receiving the following error using R in Power BI to forecast a graph:

> R script error.
> Error in dataset$total_cases :
> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> Calls:aggregate
> Execution halted <

Script below:

```
dataset <- na.omit(date)
dataset <- aggregate(dataset$total_cases, by=list(dataset$date), FUN = length)
names(dataset) <- c('date', 'Count')
dataset$date <- substr(dataset$date,1,10)

library(forecast)
ts <- ts(dataset$Count, frequency = 7)

arima.ts <- auto.arima(ts)

pred <- forecast(arima.ts, h=7)

d <- dataset$date
dl <- d(seq(1, length(d), 7))

plot(pred,axes = FALSE
    main = 'Forecast For The Next 7 Days')
axis(2)
axis(1,
    at = seq(1:(length(dl)+1)),
    labels = (c(dc,'pred')),
    cex.axis = 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clearly specify the problem here? Power BI can produce a number of innovative outputs, so it would be good to know what your ideal end goal is, and the issue you are experiencing.

Thanks,
M

Comment: This is not an answer. Post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring in your second line of code. It means that you're trying to subset a function. Make sure that "dataset" is an actual data frame object and that "total_cases" is a column name in dataset.

We don't have your data, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks, how would i make sure that 'dataset' is an actual data frame object?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reflection, this appears to be user error